# Why can't I reference System.Net.Sockets in a Portable Class Library using Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

I am trying to use System.Net.Sockets API in a portable class library so that my projects can reuse code for socket connections. But I cannot reference that namespace in my code.

As I understand it, PCLs limit you to assemblies that are available on all targeted platforms. But I am targeting ios, Android, and .Net 4.5 (using Xamarin), and all of these should have the system.dll assembly that contains the API. What am I missing?

Comment: Good question! None of the types in the [System.Net.Sockets namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.aspx) are included in any Portable Class Library profile (PCL icon not displayed in front of any *System.Net.Sockets* type). I guess it hasn't been relevant before when the `Socket` implementations have been different on every MS target. But who knows what the future has in store if MS and Xamarin integrate further; maybe there will eventually be a dedicated .NET/Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.iOS PCL profile with `Socket` functionality :-) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is right now, there is **no** PCL profile targeting only

- .NET Framework (4/4.03/4.5/4.5.1)
- Xamarin.Android
- Xamarin.iOS

If you for example attempt to define a Portable Class Library with only these targets, the project PCL profile will automatically add the *Silverlight 5* target:

[image: Silverlight 5 automatically added to PCL]

Even though *Silverlight 5* itself does support some of the [System.Net.Sockets namespace types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets(v=vs.95).aspx), none of these types have been transferred to any PCL profile. As far as I can tell, the PCL *System.Net* functionality is limited to HTTP networking.

For example, if *.NET Framework 4.5* is selected, this will correspond to PCL profile 24, for which the *System.Net.dll* contents are as follows:

[image]

Comment: How did you get that screenshot?  Where the DLL is scoped to a particular profile?

Comment: @makerofthings7 The screenshots are from VS 2013 (with Xamarin PCL targets added) and Jetbrains Dot Peek, respectively. In the Dot Peek screenshot, I have opened the *System.NET* DLL for PCL Profile 24.

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to install that tool.  I assume you manually browsed there. I checked my Reference Assemblies directory and dont see it, where did you locate the DLL?

Comment: Here is the path to my profile 24 reference assemblies: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile24*

Comment: I have tried different target combinations, but the System.Net.Sockets namespace is still unavailable. What are the options to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Using advanced PCL development AKA "Bait and switch" you may be able to do this

see [link](http://gonemobile.io/blog/e0011-portable-class-libraries-with-james-montemagno/)