# Install System.Net.Sockets on xamarin forms pcl

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin.forms, tcpclient, system.net.sockets

I have a problem. I need to use TcpClient on xamarin forms, but the "System.Net.Sockets" won't install. I can not use Nuget to install it.

The error is.:

> Could not install package 'System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0'. You are trying
>   to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

[image]

On iOS and Android projects this is able to install, but on this portable project it won't install.

How could I solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: well if you can install it in iOs and android then you are half the way , you can just call them from the portable class . Because if it is not installable on the PCL there is just a little that you can do , among that little is to copy the code of "System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0." and use the classes that you need . probably it uses some other libraries that are not supported by PCL

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Net.Sockets/ here exist for pcl...is support this in xamarin forms

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045075/why-cant-i-reference-system-net-sockets-in-a-portable-class-library-using-xamar/24059682#24059682) on why you can't install socket class into PCL project, even if it's supported in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Apart from using some of the PCL-ready socket nuget packages, you can also opt to install the System.Net.Socket to Android & iOS, and invoke them through [DependencyServices.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [this plugin](https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl)

A tpc listner

```
var listenPort = 11000;
var listener = new TcpSocketListener();

// when we get connections, read byte-by-byte from the socket's read stream
listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) => 
{
    var client = args.SocketClient; 

    var bytesRead = -1;
    var buf = new byte[1];

    while (bytesRead != 0)
    {
        bytesRead = await args.SocketClient.ReadStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, 1);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
            Debug.Write(buf[0]);
    }
};

// bind to the listen port across all interfaces
await listener.StartListeningAsync(listenPort);
```

Otherwise you can try to implement the Socket in Platform Specific code..

Comment: Hi alessandro, now I use this plugin but the async mode lost receive bytes

Comment: I think you can open a Issue on Github