# System.Net.Sockets does not exist

Tags: c#

I have got namespace directory issue and then I tried to add `System.Net.Sockets` the following

[image]

my project targets `.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=xxxx`

I even tried to install it via nuget and the latest version gives me the following issue

> Could not install package 'System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0'. You are trying
>   to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

Comment: Perhaps it's not present in the PCL profile you're targeting? (Do you really need to use a PCL profile rather than targeting netstandard, btw?)

Comment: [Possible dupe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045075/why-cant-i-reference-system-net-sockets-in-a-portable-class-library-using-xamar)

Comment: Woow John Skeet here :-) What do you suggest?

Comment: Some libraries is not built as a PCL and it is not cross platform. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674042/windows-phone-8-1-cant-reference-system-data

Comment: Is there an alternate way to check  `TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);` in PCL?

Comment: @hotspring he already explained the cause and suggested.  Read his words carefully.